# Using VBA to copy one slide from a source file and pasting to one ppt file (destination). Repeat this for 44 slides and 44 files

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

There is a ppt file with 44 slides in it and then I have a folder with 44 ppt files in it. Through the below code what I am trying to do is to open the ppt file (with 44 slides) and copy the 1st slide and then open the 1st file in destination folder (44 ppt files) and paste the copied slide after the 2nd slide.
I have to do this in loop.
Basically, I have summaries of one slide (44 slides for 44 files) and I want to copy and paste each slide one by one into these 44 files.

Problem with my code is that I am not able to break loop. Code currently does,
(1) copy the 1st slide
(2)opening the 1st file from destination
(3)deleting the 3rd slide
(4)paste after 2nd slide in the destination file
(5)close and save the destination file
(6)call the next slide and repeat step 3 & 4 & 5 (basically copying 1st slide in all the files)
(7)Next slideIndex copy the 2nd slide and repeat step 2 to 6 again

Now this loop is where I am stuck. Ideally after step 5 it should open the 2nd file and copy the 2nd slide and repeat the paste process.

If I move Next SlideIndex command before loop it starts copying all the slides and start putting in all the files - again stuck.

Please help

```
Sub CopyPasteMultipleSlide()
  ' Set the source path, destination folder, and paste after slide number from Excel cells
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim destFolder As String
    Dim pasteAfterSlide As Integer
    Dim deleteslide As Integer
    
    ' Assuming source path is in cell A1, destination folder in B1, and slide number in C1
    sourcePath = Range("B2").Value
    destFolder = Range("B3").Value
    pasteAfterSlide = Range("B6").Value
    deleteslide = Range("B7").Value
    
    ' Create PowerPoint objects
    Dim pptApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to get an existing instance of PowerPoint
    Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If PowerPoint is not running, create a new instance
    If pptApp Is Nothing Then
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    
    pptApp.Visible = True ' Set to True if you want PowerPoint to be visible
    
    ' Open the source PowerPoint file
    Dim sourcePPT As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourcePPT = pptApp.Presentations.Open(sourcePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if the source file opened successfully
    If sourcePPT Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error opening the source PowerPoint file."
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
        ' Loop through each destination PowerPoint file in the folder
        Dim destFileName As String
        destFileName = Dir(destFolder & "*.pptx")

        Do While destFileName <> ""
            ' Construct the destination file path
            Dim destFile As String
            destFile = destFolder & destFileName

            ' Create a new destination PowerPoint application
            Dim destPPTApp As Object
            Set destPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
            destPPTApp.Visible = True ' Set to True if you want PowerPoint to be visible

            ' Open the destination PowerPoint file
            Dim destPPT As Object
            On Error Resume Next
            Set destPPT = destPPTApp.Presentations.Open(destFile)
            On Error GoTo 0

            ' Check if the destination file opened successfully
            If destPPT Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Error opening the destination PowerPoint file: " & destFile & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Description
                Exit Sub
            End If
                
            ' Delete the original 3rd slide in the destination file (which becomes 4th after pasting the source slide)
            If destPPT.Slides.Count >= 3 Then
                destPPT.Slides(deleteslide).Delete
            Else
                MsgBox "Error: Slide to delete not found in the destination file."
            End If
                      
            ' Loop through each slide in the source file
            Dim slideIndex As Integer
            For slideIndex = 1 To sourcePPT.Slides.Count
            ' Copy the current slide from the source file
                sourcePPT.Slides(slideIndex).Copy
                             
            
            ' Paste the copied slide into the destination file after the specified slide number
            With destPPT.Slides.Paste(pasteAfterSlide + 1)
            End With
            
            ' Save and close the destination file
            destPPT.Save
            destPPT.Close
                       
            ' Get the next destination file in the folder
            destFileName = Dir
        Loop
    Next slideIndex

    ' Close the source file without saving changes
    sourcePPT.Close (MsoTriState.msoFalse)

    ' Release the PowerPoint objects
    Set sourcePPT = Nothing
    ' Do not quit PowerPoint to keep it open for further use

    ' Notify the user that the process is complete
    MsgBox "Slides copied and replaced successfully!", vbInformation, "Process Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Do` and `For`-loops are crossing each other. Fix your indenting then you should find the issue. Also `With destPPT.Slides.Paste(pasteAfterSlide + 1)
            End With` doesn't make sense ...

Comment: You don't need to create a new PowerPoint object for the destination file; PPT only allows one instance of itself. Just use the already created instance, pptApp, and call its .Presentations.Open method to open your destination presentation.